# the usage of 'precisely'

Tags: usage, adverbs

I've encountered a phrase, ***in precisely the wrong direction***. In this sentence what does ***precisely*** modify? Does it modify the noun phrase, ***the wrong direction***? It doesn't because ***precisely*** is an adverb. So, does it modify ***in the wrong direction***? Among the following sentences, (A) is correct while (B) and (C) don't seem to be correct. Please, explain to me the usage of ***precisely*** in this position.

- (A) Trump refugee proposal takes the nation ***in precisely the wrong direction***.
- (B) Trump refugee proposal takes the nation ***precisely in the wrong direction***.
- (C) Trump refugee proposal takes the nation ***in the precisely wrong direction***.

Answer (score 2):

"It doesn't because precisely is an adverb." This is incorrect; adverbs can, indeed, modify nouns. According to [CoGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language),

> a few intensifiers may premodify noun phrases and precede the determiner in doing so. The most common of these among adverbs are *quite* and *rather*. (section 7.63)

Section 8.16 specifically calls "precisely" a "focusing subjunct" belonging to the subdivision of "restrictives" (which "indicate that the utterance concerned is true in respect of the part focused") and then to the subset of "exclusives" (which "restrict the application of the utterance *exclusively* to the part focused").

Among your sentences, A is correct because the adverb "precisely" modifies the noun phrase "the wrong direction". In B it seems to modify the verb "takes", while in C it seems to modify the adjective "wrong"; neither of those meanings seems to be what the author intended.